# How do I access individual pixels in an image within Google App Engine (Java)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I need to be able to download an image from a remote web server, and then access the RGB colors of individual pixels in the image.  Specifically, I need to convert the image to an int[][] where each int is the RGB encoded value of the pixel.

I assume I can grab the image by downloading it using a HttpURLConnection, and then turn it into a com.google.appengine.api.images.Image using ImageServiceFactory.makeImage().

But based on what I've seen of the GAE images API, I can't see any way to access individual pixels in this image, so I can't convert it to an int[][].

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm having this same problem right now. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to find a good solution, although I vaguely recall hearing that Google have said they will provide this functionality, not sure when though.

Comment: Right after SSL over custom domains, probably ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is - "you can't", however I believe Google has said that they will be supporting this in the future.